# How to REDEFINE and perform arithmetic on a PIC X clause in COBOL

Tags: cobol

I need to move a PIC X defined field that has numerics with a 2 position decimal to a numeric field to perform an arithmatic function involving a comp-3 field. What is the best way to do this?

I did do a redefine from the PIC X to a PIC 9 with the following:
EX. PIC X(10) to PIC 9(7).99.

But now how do I perform a computation with that redefined field? Do I redefine the redefined field?

Compute FIELD-RESULT defined as S9(9)v99 = FIELD-1 (defined as S9(9)V99) - FIELD-2(my redefined field PIC 9(7).99.

Thanks!!

Comment: I suppose representative examples of your data would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the intrinsic FUNCTION NUMVAL.

You need to have "good" data, as NUMVAL, on the Mainframe anyway, fails if given invalid data (text which is not a valid "edited" number).

```
COMPUTE X-TO-NUMERIC = FUNCTION NUMVAL ( text-data )
```

You can define like this:

```
01  TEXT-NUMBER PIC X(10).
01  EDITED-NUMBER REDEFINES TEXT-NUMBER PIC 9(7).99  (or Z(6)9.99 or Z(7)9.99 or whatever)
01  X-TO-NUMERIC PIC 9(7)V99.

MOVE EDITED-NUMBER TO X-TO-NUMERIC
```

Can still fail, or just be wrong, with invalid data.

Or, my preferred method:

```
01  CONVERTED-NUMBER PIC 9(7)V99.
01  FILLER REDEFINES CONVERTED-NUMBER.
    05  CN-INTEGER-PART PIC X(7).
    05  CN-DECIMAL-PART PIC XX.


01  TEXT-NUMBER PIC X(10).
01  FILLER REDEFINES TEXT-NUMBER.
    05  TN-INTEGER-PART  PIC X(7).
    05  TN-DECIMAL-POINT PIC X.
        88  TN-DECIMAL-POINT VALID VALUE ".".
    05  TN-DECIMAL-PART  PIC XX.

IF ( TN-INTEGER-PART NUMERIC )
AND ( TN-DECIMAL-PART NUMERIC )
AND ( TN-DECIMAL-POINT )
    MOVE TN-INTEGER-PART TO CN-INTEGER-PART
    MOVE TN-DECIMAL-PART TO CN-DECIMAL-PART
ELSE
    deal with invalid
END-IF
```

Won't fail, won't get incorrect results.

EDIT: Why haven't I suggested reference-modification? Much less easy to "read" for a human if using literals only, if using datanames, still not as clear and slower than the data-definition method, so I have changed them.

EDIT. Drawn here again by another question, I noticed: *in this example*. no need for CN-INTEGER-PART, CN-DECIMAL-PART, TN-INTEGER-PART or TN-DECIMAL-PART to be defined as numeric fields.

Answer (score 1):

In the world of COBOL, what you are trying to do is "deedit" a
numeric data type.

Given a `PIC X(10)` field holding a "number" convert it to a numeric data type. If this "number" is
always guaranteed to have the same format: 7 digits, a decimal point and 2 
more digits after the decimal, the classic way
of doing this in COBOL is:

```
01.
   02 NUM-AS-PIC         PIC X(10).
   03 NUM-EDITED  REDEFINES NUM-AS-PIC PIC 9(7).99.

01 NUM-DEEDITED            PIC 9(7)V99.

MOVE '1234567.89' TO NUM-AS-PIC      <- alpha-numeric move
MOVE NUM-EDITED   TO NUM-DEEDITED    <- deediting numeric move

ADD 1 TO NUM-DEEDITED                <- numeric computation

MOVE NUM-DEEDITED  TO NUM-EDITED     <- recover explicit decimal (editing)
DISPLAY NUM-AS-PIC                   <- alpha-numeric display
```

The major drawback is that it is not very flexible. You will always need
to ensure that `NUM-AS-PIC` contains exactly the correct format. For example

```
MOVE '123.45'  TO NUM-AS-PIC
```

would result in a runtime error because the decimal place is in the wrong position
(`MOVE` fills from the left as opposed to the right) and
trailing spaces are padded after it making up the remaining 4 bytes (and spaces are not valid numeric values).

Another common method is to employ the `NUMVAL` function. This function takes any
valid edited number format and converts it to a floating point numeric representation.
The numeric value may have leading or trailing spaces appended to it. The result of `NUMVAL` may be assigned to any valid numeric data type. For example:

```
  MOVE '1234567.89' TO NUM-AS-PIC         <- alpha-numeric move
  COMPUTE NUM-DEEDITED = FUNCTION NUMVAL(NUM-AS-PIC)
```

Now

```
  MOVE '123.45' TO NUM-AS-PIC 
  COMPUTE NUM-DEEDITED = FUNCTION NUMVAL(NUM-AS-PIC)
```

results in a valid move too. However, a runtime error still occurs if the
value contained in `NUM-AS-PIC` cannot be converted to a valid floating point number.
For example:

```
  MOVE '12A.23' TO NUM-AS-PIC
  COMPUTE NUM-DEEDITED = FUNCTION NUMVAL(NUM-AS-PIC)
```

will still result in a runtime error.

The sad news is that there is no universally easy or fool-proof way of doing
this in COBOL.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that last sentence. If leading/trailing blanks they can be dealt with (trailing blanks need the "Goldilocks" definition, "JUST RIGHT" or "JUSTIFIED RIGHT". Variably-located decimal point is also OK. I suppose "universally easy" is the kicker, in that often there is an expectation that "some magic" will do everything for you, and there's no need for any real code :-)