# How to pass a real decimal value into a virtual decimal value?

Tags: variables, cobol, mainframe

I have a `PIC 9(14).9(2)` variable that receives data from an incoming file. I wish to pass it into a report variable that is a `PIC 9(14)V9(2)`. The format of incoming data can't be altered. Is there any way I can pass one value into another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pic 9(14).9(2) is essentially a Pic X field. You could set up redefine fields
or use reference modification

i.e.

```
       03 F1                 PIC 9(14).9(2).
       03 filler redefines F1.
          05 F1-Int          pic 9(14).
          05 filler          pic X.
          05 F1-decimal      pic 9(2).

       03 F2                 PIC 9(14)V9(2).
       03 filler redefines F2.
          05 F2-Int          pic 9(14).
          05 F2-decimal      pic 9(2).

       Move F1-int          to f2-int.
       Move F1-decimal      to f2-decimal.

or    
       Move F1(1:14)        to F2(1:14).   
       Move F1(16:2)        to F2(15:2).   // Forgoten the correct format for cobol
```

Comment: thanks. Got it sorted out already in a similar fashion but yes, your method is much efficient. :)

Comment: Which efficient method did you use, and "efficient" in terms of what, if you don't mind me asking?

Answer (score 1):

You could also look here: [How to REDEFINE and perform arithmetic on a PIC X clause in COBOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371578/how-to-redefine-and-perform-arithmetic-on-a-pic-x-clause-in-cobol/14375295#14375295), which is (possibly) a similar topic (although the format of the input data was never confirmed)